# Why is this spark sql query for the sum of a column returning null?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**My input:**

```python
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|    TransactionDate|Product Major Code|Gross Trade Sales|
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|2017-09-30 00:00:00|                 A|            100.0|
|2017-06-30 00:00:00|                 B|            200.0|
|2017-06-30 00:00:00|                 C|            300.0|
+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

**My code:**

```python
df.registerTempTable("tmp")
df2=spark.sql("SELECT TransactionDate,'Product Major Code', sum('Gross Trade Sales') FROM tmp GROUP BY TransactionDate,'Product Major Code'")
spark.catalog.dropTempView('tmp')
```

**My output:**

```python
+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+
|    TransactionDate|Product Major Code|sum(CAST(Gross Trade Sales AS DOUBLE))|
+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+
|2017-09-30 00:00:00|Product Major Code|                                  null|
|2017-06-30 00:00:00|Product Major Code|                                  null|
+-------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Anyone know why it's not correctly aggregating Product Major code and Gross Trade Sales?

**Update:**

I went in the end with PaulITs answer below as it was more elegant and doesn't have to worry about backticks:

`import pyspark.sql.functions as f
 trydf.groupBy(f.col("TransactionDate"), f.col("Product Major Code")).agg(f.sum(f.col("Gross Trade Sales"))).show()`

Comment: Try wrapping `Gross Trade Sales` and `Product Major Code` in backticks. As written you are trying to sum the literal string `"Gross Trade Sales"` casted as a double, which is `null`.

Comment: Wow that actually worked! Would never have guessed that --that's not python-esque is it? Either way post it as an answer so I can award you the points.

Comment: IMO you should accept the duplicate target instead.

Comment: I would also add that you can achieve the same from the API functions: First `import pyspark.sql.functions as f` and then try`df.groupBy(f.col("TransactionDate"), f.col("Product Major Code")).agg(f.sum(f.col("Gross Trade Sales"))).show()`